# How to check username and change it depending on the username

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to create an automatic function that checks if a username contains anything else other than numbers and letters. I've attempted to do this but I have yet to have a working one.
I've used this and even tried to catch the errors, but it doesn't work and yet does not produce an error. I don't really know what the problem is. I'm fairly new to JS and discord bot creation so I'm not very good with this.

```js
bot.on("guildMemberAdd", k => {
  if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission(["MANAGE_NICKNAMES", "ADMINISTRATOR"])) return message.channel.send("I do not meet the permission criteria!")
  let user = bot.users.cache
  if (user.user.username != /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '_') {
    try {

      let i = 1
      user.user.setNickname('Pingable Name #' + i + 1)
    } catch (e) {
      return console.log(e);
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm seeing multiple issues with your code:

- You're calling a `message` variable which is not defined in your code, since your handler is receiving the new guild member (which you named `k`), and not a message. Check the docs for the [`guildMemberAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd) event for more info.
- You're defining `user` as `bot.users.cache` (and so as a Collection of users), but then you use it as if it was the guild member: that's wrong, but you also don't need to do it since you already have the guild member as the argument of the function.
- You're using `user.user.username != /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '_'` to check whether the username matches this regex, but this is invalid syntax.

Let's see how you can fix them:

```js
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', newMember => {
  // You can avoid checking for the admin permission, since if it's present it will work by default
  if (!newMember.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_NICKNAMES")) {
    // Using message.channel.send is impossible, since message is not defined.
    // return message.channel.send("I do not meet the permission criteria!")
    // You can try sending a message to the owner:
    return newMember.guild.owner.send('Can\'t change nickname: missing permissions')
  }

  // You can get the user from the guild member
  let user = newMember.user

  // Use the Regex.test() method
  let regex = /[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/g // I've added the _ inside the regex
  if (regex.test(user.username)) {
    try {
      // I'm removing the i variable since it's not being changed and it's not in global scope, 
      // you would need to store it somewhere in order for it to work
      // let i = 1

      // The setNickname method exists only inside the GuildMember class
      newMember.setNickname('Pingable Name')
    } catch (e) {
      return console.log(e);
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: thanks! worked like a charm, i appreciate the explanation and everything so i can learn! :D

Comment: Happy to hear that ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (user.user.username != /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g.test(user.user.username));
```

Try something like this.

Comment: While the regex syntax is correct, a non-empty string can't be equal to a boolean value (returned by the test method), so that will always return `true`. Also, there are other issue in the code related to the library